# Events created using the Advanced Calendar API not showing up on Google Calendar Android app

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm adding all-day events to a calendar using the following code:

```
function main() {
  const response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(API_URL).getContentText());
  const forecasts = response.daily;

  deleteEvents_();
  forecasts.forEach(e => {
    const forecast = new Forecast(e);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(forecast));
    console.log(forecast.getForecastText());
    Calendar.Events.insert(createEvent_(forecast.getForecastText(), forecast.date), CAL_ID);
  });
}

function createEvent_(summary, date) {
  const formattedDate = DateUtils.toYYYYMMDD(date, "-");
  return {
    summary: summary,
    start: {
      date: formattedDate
    },
    end: {
      date: formattedDate
    },
    transparency: "transparent"
  };
}

function deleteEvents_() {
  const today = new Date();
  const from = DateUtils.addDays(today, -1);
  const to = DateUtils.addDays(today, 7);
  console.log(`Retrieving events from ${from} to ${to}`);
  Calendar.Events.list(CAL_ID, {timeMin: from.toISOString(), timeMax: to.toISOString()}).items.forEach(event => {
    console.log(`Deleting: ${event.summary}`);
    Calendar.Events.remove(CAL_ID, event.id);
  })
}
```

I can see the events on the web version of Google Calendar but they don't show up on the app. I created another all-day event manually to test, and the one I created manually shows up on both the web version and the app. So next I got the properties of the manually-added event and one of the events I created via my script to see if there was any difference using `Calendar.Events.list(CAL_ID, {timeMin: new Date("2022-04-30").toISOString(), timeMax: new Date("2022-05-01").toISOString()});`.

Manually-created event:

```
{
  id: 'xxxxxxxx',
  creator: { email: 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com' },
  end: { date: '2022-05-01' },
  created: '2022-05-01T00:49:18.000Z',
  etag: '"xxxxxxxx"',
  kind: 'calendar#event',
  organizer: {
     email: 'xxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com',
     displayName: 'weather',
     self: true },
  reminders: { useDefault: false },
  htmlLink: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=xxxxxxxx',
  summary: 'test',
  transparency: 'transparent',
  updated: '2022-05-01T00:49:18.774Z',
  sequence: 0,
  start: { date: '2022-04-30' },
  iCalUID: 'xxxxxxxx@google.com',
  status: 'confirmed',
  eventType: 'default'
}
```

Script-created event:

```
{
  creator: { email: 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com' },
  updated: '2022-05-01T00:28:26.176Z',
  htmlLink: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=xxxxxxxx',
  created: '2022-05-01T00:28:26.000Z',
  sequence: 0,
  start: { date: '2022-05-01' },
  reminders: { useDefault: false },
  eventType: 'default',
  status: 'confirmed',
  etag: '"xxxxxxxx"',
  iCalUID: 'xxxxxxxx@google.com',
  end: { date: '2022-05-01' },
  organizer: { 
     self: true,
     email: 'xxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com',
     displayName: 'weather' },
  id: 'xxxxxxxx',
  summary: ' (12.97℃-16.41℃)',
  transparency: 'transparent',
  kind: 'calendar#event'
}
```

Sorry for the difference in the order of the JSON contents, I copied and pasted the response Google Apps Script gave me (except that I redacted IDs for privacy). But I don't see anything that could result in one being displayed in the Google Calendar Android app and the other not. Am I missing something? What else can I check?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (It's not clear how the funtion is called and how the event objects were retrieved)

Comment: Are you sure you are logged into the same account from your Android device?

Comment: @Rubén I have edited my question to include the rest of the main logic I used for adding and retrieving the events. I also edited the title because the events had stopped showing up in the app even if I didn't set the transparency to "transparent".

Comment: @ziganotschka Yes, I am. I have multiple calendars in the account and all my events are showing up except for the ones I created via the Advanced Calendar Services API as mentioned.

Comment: Do you experience the same problem with non-transparent events? What I can see from your JSON objects is that the script-created event starts and ends on the same day  - unlike the manually created one.

Comment: Are the two events created on the same calendar (same `iCalUID`)?  If not, check that the relevant calendar is not hidden on your Android device.

Comment: @ziganotschka That's it! I fixed my code to set the ending date to a day later and they show up on the Android app as well! I can't believe I missed that! Thank you so much!

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and this helped! @ziganotschka If you add an answer I'll happily upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @ziganotschka, for all-day events, it seems that if the start and end date are the same, they display on `calendar.google.com`, but not in the Android app.

However, if you offset the end date forward by one day (as in the manually created example), it seems to display correctly on both the website and the app.

This was hinted at in the provided JSON events:

```
// manual event
  end: { date: '2022-05-01' },
  ...
  start: { date: '2022-04-30' },

// script event
  start: { date: '2022-05-01' },
  ...
  end: { date: '2022-05-01' },
```